Как сделать проверку текстового поля, на запрещенные слова в Tilda
Всем привет. У меня есть массив запрещенных слов и инпут в zero block. Нужно что бы перед отправкой, инпут проверялся на наличие этих слов. Форма - class="t-form t-form_inputs-total_2 js-form-proccess" id="form813363847" name="form813363847", сам инпут - name="Name" class="t-input js-tilda-rule t-input-inline-styles".
Вот мой код:
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let input = document.querySelector('[name="name"].t-input .js-tilda-rule .t-input-inline-styles');
    let form = document.querySelector('[name="form813363847"].t-form .t-form_inputs-total_2 .js-form-proccess .js-send-form-success')
    const forbiddenWords = ['запрещенные', 'слова'];
    if (input) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
            const inputValue = input.value.toLowerCase();
            const isForbidden = forbiddenWords.some((word) => inputValue.includes(word));
            if (isForbidden) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('Вы ввели запрещенное слово!');
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>

Но при отправке формы ничего не меняется. Помогите пожалуйста.

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.
